# Metric at the junction

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, boundary-conditions, dirac-delta-distributions

In general relativity, while deriving junction conditions one works with the metric $$g_{\mu\nu} = \Theta(f) g^{+}_{\mu\nu} + \Theta(-f) g^{-}_{\mu\nu} \tag{1}$$
where $f = 0$ is the junction. Now, how is the metric defined at the junction $f = 0$? One can perhaps define $\Theta(0) = 1/2$ but this will ruin the properties $$\Theta(f)^2 = \Theta(f)\tag{2}$$
$$ \Theta(f)\Theta(-f) =0 \tag{3}$$ which is needed to derive the junction conditions for the curvature tensor.
Is the metric even defined at $f =0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

E. Poisson leaves $\Theta(0)$ as an indeterminate. He writes:

> We introduce the [Heaviside distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function) $\Theta(\ell)$, equal to $+1$ if $\ell > 0$, $0$ if $\ell < 0$, and indeterminate if $\ell = 0$.

OP's eqs. (2) & (3) should apparently be understood as fulfilled [almost everywhere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_everywhere).

References:

1. Eric Poisson, *A Relativist's Toolkit,* 2004; Section 3.7.
2. Eric Poisson, [*An Advanced course in GR*](https://archive.org/details/Eric_Poisson__Advanced_general_relativity); Section 3.7.